# Do I need to re-implement authentication in Mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

My Flask application is currently uses PostgreSQL to store all authentication information (users, tokens) and interact with it. For other logic I need to use MongoDB. I like to use one technologies of one type instead of multiple to reduce complexity of an application (for example, only Redis instead of Redis + memcached).

So for now I'm thinking about using MongoDB only, using it as backend for authentication process.

Current workflow is following: PostgreSQL stores two tables: User and Token. When I sign up user, I open transaction, store his data (username, login, password) in User table, then insert activation token to Token table, then send activation letter, then close transaction. So, problem occurred in storing User, Token or later in code, when I'll try to send email, transaction will be rolled back. It prevents cases when user created, but token not, so account can't be activated.

As I know, transactions is not feature of MongoDB. So, if I will have two documents, User and Token, I will not be able to rollback creating of first if second can't be created.

My questions are:

1. How would you implement described behavior on MongoDB?
2. Is it good idea to use only MongoDB for all stuff instead of PostgreSQL for authentication and MongoDB for documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do have to implement the signup logic yourself in this case. For example if you store the following document:

```
user : {
    name : 'Alex Black'
    email : 'alex@example.com'
    token : {
        value : 'some_random_token'     # subject for indexing
        expires : '00.00.00.18.11.2012' # use MongoDB date here
    }
}
```

Then e.g. a cron script should remove all the expired users. But a trick would be in using the NoSQL features of Mongo!

Just create two separate collections: `Users` and e.g. `UnregisteredUsers`. Store the user information to `UnregisteredUsers` and only when registration is confirmed transfer the `user` document from `UnregisteredUsers` to `Users`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As I understood, in common case if I need several-steps operations, I need to do them in one object context. Is it right?

Comment: @Marboni and but "one object context" you mean...?

Comment: I mean that if I need to change two objects "in one transaction" in MongoDB, first must be located in second.

Comment: Well, changing multiple documents "in one transaction" is possible and simple in MongoDB. But that statement is true as long as the documents belong to one collection. AFAIK, the Mongo query syntax is per-single-collection only. So, to move the document from one collection to the other you have to 1. Read it to memory from collection A. 2. Write it to collection B. 3. Remove it from collection A.

Comment: Also, a good article on simulating transactions in MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/